# How can I build partial dependence plots with brt shapes?

Tags: r, plot

I am not practice in R and I need some help. I am an ecologist, I have a sites by variables matrix, where "TD0", "TD1", "TD2" are the response variables and "Chao", "age", "slope" the explanatory variables.

```
ID.plot TD0    TD1    TD2      Chao age slope
1 GS_Ci01N  20  8.898  6.488 0.6521390  26     2
2 GS_Ci03N  26  7.788  4.883 0.2335441  26     2
3 GS_Ci04N  31 10.482  7.282 0.5234748  26     0
4 GS_Ci05N  47 18.108 11.989 0.3110385  26     3
5 GS_Ci06N  47 16.332 10.107 0.4529010  26     0
6 GS_Ci07N  31  9.478  5.725 0.5524426  26     1

db.chao <- read.table(text=db.chao, header = TRUE)
```

I built boosted regression trees (BRT) to define the thresholds from explanatory-response shapes. I used "dismo" and "gbm" packages.

mod0 <- gbm.step(data=db.chao, gbm.x = 5:7, gbm.y = 2, family = "poisson", tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.0025, bag.fraction = 0.5)

mod1 <- gbm.step(data=db.chao, gbm.x = 5:7, gbm.y = 3, family = "gaussian", tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.0025, bag.fraction = 0.5)

mod2 <- gbm.step(data=db.chao, gbm.x = 5:7, gbm.y = 4, family = "gaussian", tree.complexity = 5, learning.rate = 0.0025, bag.fraction = 0.5)

I obtained three models:

- "mod0" which describes the relation between TD0 and the explanatory variables
- "mod1" which describes the relation between TD1 and the explanatory variables
- "mod2" which describes the relation between TD2 and the explanatory variables

For each of them I built the panel graphs as below (these are just examples):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7UUD.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnfnz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBqZJ.jpg)

**For each response variable I have three graphs**, one for each explanatory variable.

I obtained them with this script:

```
gbm.plot(mod.TD0, n.plots = 3, write.title= FALSE, main = "TD0", rug = T, smooth = TRUE, plot.layout=c(1,3), common.scale = T)

gbm.plot(mod.TD1, n.plots = 3, write.title= FALSE, main = "TD1", rug = T, smooth = TRUE, plot.layout=c(1,3), common.scale = T)

gbm.plot(mod.TD2, n.plots = 3, write.title= FALSE, main = "TD2", rug = T, smooth = TRUE, plot.layout=c(1,3), common.scale = T)
```

Actually I would like to have **three graphs, one for each explanatory variable** and, after that if possible, in each of them I would like to **overlap the three response variables shapes** (with three different lines or colors).

I suppose I should use the "pdp" package for constructing partial dependence plots, but I'm not able to do this.

If someone could help me I would be grateful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how a gbm works and why it needs the number of trees to predict the output but here is a working example using the `pdp` and `gridExtra` packages:

```
library(pdp)
ntrees <- 250 # Number of trees to use to predict data
pred <- function(object, newdata) {
  pred <- predict(object, newdata, n.trees = ntrees)
  mean(pred)
}
pdps1 <- pdps2 <- pdps3 <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  pdps1[[i]] <- partial(mod0, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                       train = db.chao, plot = TRUE, 
                       pred.fun = pred, recursive = F)
  pdps2[[i]] <- partial(mod1, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                       train = db.chao, plot = TRUE,
                       pred.fun = pred, recursive = F)
  pdps3[[i]] <- partial(mod2, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                       train = db.chao, plot = TRUE,
                       pred.fun = pred, recursive = F)
}
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = pdps1, nrow = 1) # For the first model
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = pdps2, nrow = 1) # For the second model
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = pdps3, nrow = 1) # For the third model
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT

Following with the request of OP to obtain all pdps in only three plots and with different number of trees to predict the values:

```
library(pdp)
ntrees1 <- 150 # Number of trees to use to predict data with model1
ntrees2 <- 250 # Number of trees to use to predict data with model2
ntrees3 <- 50 # Number of trees to use to predict data with model3
pred1 <- function(object, newdata) {
  pred <- predict(object, newdata, n.trees = ntrees1)
  mean(pred)
}
pred2 <- function(object, newdata) {
  pred <- predict(object, newdata, n.trees = ntrees2)
  mean(pred)
}
pred3 <- function(object, newdata) {
  pred <- predict(object, newdata, n.trees = ntrees3)
  mean(pred)
}
# Function to obtain legend to plot later in grid.arrange
get_legend<-function(myggplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myggplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
}
# Obtain partial dependence data instead of plot
pdps1 <- pdps2 <- pdps3 <- list()
plotlist <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  # Create local environment to prevent ggplot to overwrite the plots with the iterator 
  local({
    i <- i
    pdps1[[i]] <<- partial(mod0, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                          train = db.chao, plot = FALSE, 
                          pred.fun = pred1, recursive = F)
    pdps2[[i]] <<- partial(mod1, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                          train = db.chao, plot = FALSE,
                          pred.fun = pred2, recursive = F)
    pdps3[[i]] <<- partial(mod2, pred.var = names(db.chao)[i+4], 
                          train = db.chao, plot = FALSE,
                          pred.fun = pred3, recursive = F)
    pdp <- rbind(pdps1[[i]],pdps2[[i]],pdps3[[i]])
    pdp <- cbind(pdp,rep(c("y1","y2","y3"), each = nrow(pdps1[[i]])))
    names(pdp)[3] <- "#output"

    plotlist[[i]] <<- ggplot(pdp) +
      geom_line(aes(x = pdp[,1], y = pdp[,2], 
                    group = pdp[,3], color = pdp[,3])) +
      xlab(names(pdp)[1]) + ylab("yhat") + 
      ggtitle(paste0("PDP of ",names(pdp)[1])) +
      labs(color = "#output")

  })
  legend <- get_legend(plotlist[[i]])
  plotlist[[i]] <- plotlist[[i]] + theme(legend.position = "none")
}
plotlist[[4]] <- legend

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plotlist, nrow = 1, widths=c(2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 0.8))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Actually, in this way I would obtain nine graphs (three per model). But I would like to build just three graphs, one for each explanatory variable, and in each of them I would like to see the shapes of the three response variables together overlapped. Could you help me? Moreover, each model has a different number of trees. I can not use just one "ntrees" value. Finally, why do you use [i+4]? What does 4 mean?

Comment: See the edit to use different n.trees for each model and all the pdps in only three plots. The [i+4] is only because the way in you have built your data.frame your explanatory variables is the 5th, 6th and 7th, due to iterator go from 1 to 3 you need to add 4 to select the explanatory variables when calculating the pdp in the `for loop`